# Meteor Android SDK install

Tags: android, node.js, meteor

I am trying out meteor for android and for the first time. I have a simple todo meteor example app at my directory. I already have android studio and eclipse for android installed. When i run this command

> meteor install-sdk android

I get following error

```
Installing Android bundle
✓ A JDK is installed                          
Installing Android Platform tools             

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:720:19)
```

I could not figure out what the real problem is.

Comment: Looks like the connection is being closed as Meteor is trying to download the Platform Tools.  Any chance of a connection issue at your end?  If not, I'd try again later and see if it's a problem at the remote end that's been resolved.

Comment: everything else is working fine in my pc, regarding connection. i don't think thats the issue. i google a bit and i found same problem with others as well, but could not find the solution

Comment: are you behind a proxy or  similar?

Comment: no, there is no problem with my connection

Comment: @richsilv is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm afraid. Have you posted in the meteor-talk forum? You might have some luck there.

Comment: @richsilv yes, i did, no luck there as well. I dont think i am the only one experiencing this problem.

Comment: Stuck in same problem.. any fix yet?

Comment: yes.. i created a new user account on my mac, reinstalled the meteor and change the .meteor directory/subdirectories and sub files to permission 777 (chmod). 

sudo find /Users/<user_name>/<meteor_app_directory>/.meteor/local/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

sudo find /Users/<user_name>/<meteor_app_directory>/.meteor/local/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;

Answer (score 0):

Did it,

Created a new user account, reinstalled the meteor and changed all the directories to permission 777

```
sudo find /Users/<user_name>/<meteor_app_dir>/.meteor/local/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

and all the files inside it to 777 as well

```
sudo find /Users/<user_name>/<meteor_app_dir>/.meteor/local/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```